# Benefit to LIMIT on query that searches via PK

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

Let's say I have a website that displays blog posts. And on this webpage there is a comment section but it's hidden on page load. However the comment count is displayed for the user in it's place and if the user clicks the count an ajax call is made to load all of the comments.

Normally I do a little extra coding to grab the comment count from the page, and then send it to the backend so that I can put a limit on my query. So instead of this...

```
SELECT * FROM comments INNER JOIN post WHERE post.id = 1
```

I can do this...

```
SELECT * FROM comments INNER JOIN post WHERE post.id = 1 LIMIT 15
```

So now that I've implemented this I'm wondering, **is there any benefit to a query that searches via primary key to deliberately tell the query how may rows are on that primary key**? I did an SQL EXPLAIN with and without the limit but they're the same. My main concern and the reason I am asking this is b/c **I would like to make sure that the query does not do a full table scan** and that's why I've always had the habit of adding the limit.

Comment: The query plan might be the same, but did you notice any difference in execution times, or how many tuples were read?  Also more than likely you're referring to a `FK` (foreign key), since a primary key would be unique and only appear once per table

Comment: @gmustudent Can you please mark a different answer as accepted?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You want to limit the result set of your joining result set... You also don't want to guess what the `LIMIT` is because the records will change. There is a cost to return a subset of the result set.

Comment: Very true. The subset part really made me think. Thank you!

Comment: nose, your answer was not that bad and I don't really get why it has been downvoted so much...

Comment: I don't think it answered the question at all. It should have been a comment.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong on many levels. You're adding a -relatively- inmense overhead for a query that works fine just by itself (even if it requires some finishing: see Bill's answer)

If you build a proper query (*and a proper model*), you won't have any performance problem. By trying little tricks like this you're going to

1- have a performance problem at some time (see the excellent mysql performance blog's [article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/) about the order by desc and limit optimizer issue)

2- make a spaghetti in your code (the first thing I would wonder reading your code is: "why is that so?". Also, things like this add up and at the end, this is a lot of "noise". Stick to the main line, that's my advice)

3- have unexpected results (what if there's a sudden 16th comment appearing between your 2 queries?)

That came from a good intention but I think it is a bad idea.